# Remove class from single div of a sequence that was rendered through map

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am rendering a sequence of divs with some content and a button. All divs have a certain class on them and they also have a button. When I click on that button, I want to remove the class of the div that it belongs to. My render code looks like this:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        arr.map(x => {
          return (
            <div className={this.state.displayClass ? 'someClass' : ''}>
              <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}> Remove class <button>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

For the button click, I am simply setting the `displayClass` to false and I successfully remove the div:

```
handleClick () {
  this.setState({ displayClass: false })
}
```

The problem here obviously is that the way I'm doing it, it will remove all classes from all divs. So my question is how can I make each button click to only remove the class from it's own div?

Comment: The react way is to make the class a part of the state using an array, or to turn the `<div>` inside the loop into a stateful component.

Comment: What the best way to fix this is depends on whether the app has to know about the class state of an individual div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just extract each div into separate component with his own state:

```
class ClassManagableDiv extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    displayClass: true
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ displayClass: false })
  }

  render() {
    return <div className={this.state.displayClass ? 'someClass' : ''}>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Remove class </button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

And next apply it to your array:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        arr.map(x => <ClassManagableDiv />)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stateful component for the individual `div` that will contain that state. Then when you click on the button, it will only update the state of that component, not of all.

Answer (score 0):

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        arr.map(x => {
          return (
            <div className={this.state.displayClass ? 'someClass' : ''}>
              <button onClick={(ev) => this.handleClick(ev,"someClass")}> Remove class <button>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
```

}

and

```
handleClick (ev,classN) {
    ev.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.remove(classN)
}
```

what it does ? you sen de event "ev" when calling handleClick plus add the className to be removed, then in handleClick you get that target el that fired the event, then look for its parent / which is the one that holds the class / and remove it

Comment: return (
            <div className="classes here">
              <button onClick={(ev) => this.handleClick(ev,"someClass")}> Remove class <button>
            </div>
          )